# Recommended data format/structure for saving many tags belonging to files?

Tags: c#, .net, file, tags, format

My goal is to efficiently and simply save tags belonging to image files in a directory. The tags should be stored inside a file that is created.

Let's say in the directory, there is a file 'duck.jpg'. Then p.e. I would like to assign tags 'animal' and 'bird' to this file. The tags are assigned with an image slider, where you tick off checkboxes, and then the tags should be associated with the files.

My question is what data structure / file format would be optimal for this problem. I thought about JSON, XML etc.

The resulting file should not be too big, as tags for many images will be stored, and it must be loadable quickly again and extendable (e.g. adding a new file to the structure should be possible).

What approach would be best suited for the problem?

Comment: Are limited in options? or a database will be fine?

Comment: I want to keep it as simple/compact as possible. Everything should be saved in one single file.

Comment: You can create an index like file to store the tags and files associated with each tag, XML or JSON is fine.